# Puppeteer authentication does not work in headless mode but yes in non headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, headless, puppeteer

I'm facing up a strange problem in Puppeteer with authentication.

I've written a script to take some screenshot of a website which required authentication.

In my local computer (windows), when running in command line as node.exe my_script.js; it's working fine (in headless moden which is the default mode).

I've written an upper Java program to manipulate it (dynamically set the path, the node modules path, run the process "nodex.exe my_script.js" every 30minutes, manage timeout of the process,...). It's still working directly running from Eclipse, in headless mode.

Then... I've built/packaged a JAR and running it in a cmd window: java -jar my_jar.jar... and then the script can't authentitcated on the website in headless mode (the answser page just write a message like "you need to be authenticated", which is managed by the http server).

To check what happen, I've just add an option in my nodejs script (so I do not modify my java upper program code) to run chrome in non headless mode; with option headless : false. And... it's working!

I let the option to run in non headless mode, and I create a Windows service to run my jar via a bat file, with the help of nssm... Just to test. I'm really happy to see that all is running fine without seeing any chrome GUI (maybe Windows disable GUI for service, don't know how).

Have I maybe missed something? Or is there a bug in Puppeteer or Chrome to manage authentication in headless mode?

Regards

Alex

Comment: Any git repo showing the codes will be helpful.

Comment: https://blog.apify.com/how-to-make-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-use-a-proxy-server-with-authentication-249a21a79212